# I want the result of a user input to cause a different variable to be used

Tags: python, variables

Disclaimer I'm only 10 days into learning Python (little to no experience in any language prior to this)

I'm having difficulty conceptualizing my problem and thus, a solution for it.

I currently have the following code:

```
spacer = "_|_"
spacer_btm = " | "
blank = "_"
blank_btm = " "

print(blank + spacer + blank + spacer + blank)
print(blank + spacer + blank + spacer + blank)
print(blank_btm + spacer_btm + blank_btm + spacer_btm + blank_btm)
```

This is going to print out a grid. Originally i had the **blank** and **blank_btm** variables split into 9 separate variables, each denoting a space in the grid that I want to change. The problem I have is that since these are strings, they are immutable. I want to change that blank space/underscore value for something else based on the result of a user input. Ideally the value that replaces the **blank** or **blank_btm** would also be a string, but I'm confounded as to what sort of process I should use to get there.

for example if the input is **1** lets say that would mean the top left box in the grid gets **"A"** (or literally anything as a string)

For reference the previous code I had was

```
spacer = str("_|_")
spacer_btm = " | "
a1 = str("_")
a2 = str("_")
a3 = str("_")
b4 = str("_")
b5 = str("_")
b6 = str("_")
c7 = str(" ")
c8 = str(" ")
c9 = str(" ")
    
print(a1 + spacer + a2 + spacer + a3)
print(b4 + spacer + b5 + spacer + b6)
print(c7 + spacer_btm + c8 + spacer_btm + c9)
```

Comment: You can replace `str("...")` with `"..."` because quoted text is already of type `str`. You need `str(...)` when you want to concatenate values of different types, for example, an `int` (`-1`, `42`, etc.) and a `str`, as in `"the answer is " + str(42)` (try `"" + 42`) :-)

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution to your code I can think of is the following one.

```
spacer = "_|_"
spacer_btm = " | "
blank = "_"
blank_btm = " "

print(("A" if input() == "1" else blank) + spacer + blank + spacer + blank)
print(blank + spacer + blank + spacer + blank)
print(blank_btm + spacer_btm + blank_btm + spacer_btm + blank_btm)
```

When Python executes the `input` builtin function, the program hangs until you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

I would not do it like this but I don't want to give you a solution you would not understand. For example, I suppose you need to prompt the user repeatedly, in a read-eval-print loop, but do you know what a `while` loop is?

Answer (score 0):

I liked the answer @misterwtf gave but I'll just move a step ahead and make an assumption that you would want the grid to be fixed and would want to fill the values in the boxes, like in tic-tac-toe.

If you have studied about python dictionary, I'd suggest you to use one.

You can simply define the dict variable like:

```
board = {'9': ' ' , '8': ' ' , '7': ' ' ,
            '6': ' ' , '5': ' ' , '4': ' ' ,
            '3': ' ' , '2': ' ' , '1': ' ' }
```

and then make the grid like:

```
print(' ' + board['9'] + ' |' + ' ' + board['8'] + ' |' + ' ' + board['7'])
print('---|---|---')
print(' ' + board['6'] + ' |' + ' ' + board['5'] + ' |' + ' ' + board['4'])
print('---|---|---')
print(' ' + board['3'] + ' |' + ' ' + board['2'] + ' |' + ' ' + board['1'])
```

It would be better if you make this^ into a function (study about that as well).
Now, you can take the input from the user. Say, you want to fill the top-left box. You'll simply write:

```
board['9'] = input()
```

and now when you make the grid again, voila! you've successfully entered the value in the grid.

Comment: @Jason The `board["i"]`s are linked to some memory space in your computer. When you write `board["i"]`, the program reads the ith memory space, and when you write `board["i"] = "something"`, the program writes to the ith memory space. Try this `board = {} ; board["1"] = "a" ; print(board["1"]) ; board["1"] = "b" ; print(board["1"])`.